# Calculating the AICc and BIC with RSS instead of likelihood

Tags: model-selection, aic, bic

I have found [here](http://avesbiodiv.mncn.csic.es/estadistica/ejemploaic.pdf) that that the akaike information criteria, corrected for small sample sizes is:

[image]

where:

[image]

And that the likelihood can be replaced with residual sum of squares (RSS) divided by n, the sample size.

[image]

so that

[image]

My question is if the likelihood function and RSS are equivalent if the RSS is first divided by the sample size, can I also do the same with the Bayesian information criteria? i.e.

[image]

Also, I want to be able to reference this information in a paper (and unfortunately the link above doesn't cut it). Its easy enough to find these equations but harder to find somewhere that describes why the likelihood function is equal to the RSS divided by n. Could somebody describe why this is the case or point me to a source?

Comment: I believe this is covered in Venables and Ripley *Modern Applied Statistics in S*; basically, the log-likelihood of a set of iid Gaussian values (residuals) can be shown to be RSS/n plus a constant ...

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a direct answer in this question, but let me underline that this AIC equation is not proper. As given in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), the AIC formula with RSS (instead of likelihood) is:

$AIC = 2k + n\cdot ln(\frac{RSS}{n})$.

This could lead to major modelling problems.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, even though it's helpful.

Comment: The poster specified that they were giving the AIC corrected for small sample sizes and they gave the correct formula in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula
$$
\hat{L} = \frac{\text{RSS}}{n}
$$
(where $\hat{L}$ is the maximized likelihood)
is mostly correct up to constants for the normal model (as @Ben Bolker's comment indicates).

The math is here:

Suppose that $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ with $X$ fixed and $\varepsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)$. Then we know that the log likelihood becomes:
$$
\ell(\beta, \sigma^2) = \log \left(\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}(y-X\beta)^T(\sigma^2I)^{-1}(y - X\beta)\right) \right) = -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi \sigma^2) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y - X\beta)^T(y - X\beta) 
$$
You can find by taking derivatives with respect to $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$ that you can maximize this with the choice of
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY \\ \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}(y - X\hat{\beta})^T(y - X\hat{\beta}) = \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{RSS}
$$
So then we get that
$$
\hat{\ell} = \ell(\hat{\beta}, \hat{\sigma}^2) = -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) -\frac{n}{2}\log(\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{RSS}) - \frac{n}{2}\frac{(y - X\hat{\beta})^T(y - X\hat{\beta})}{(y - X\hat{\beta})^T(y - X\hat{\beta})}
$$
Hence
$$
\hat{\ell} = -\frac{n}{2}\log\left(\frac{\mathrm{RSS}}{n}\right) + C.
$$
Note that this is not generally true for any model and holds due to some of the peculiarities of the normal linear model.